# How to call elements of the list in for loop using something other than i?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have created a function that wraps a `group_map` that creates GT tables for every group within a data set.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

group_var <- "State"
select_vect <- c("City", "Elevation", "NumObserved")

group_var <-"State" 
select_vect <- c("City", "Elevation", "NumObserved") 

create_gts_and_map <- function(df, group_var, title_text) { 
  df %>% 
    group_by(.data[[group_var]]) %>% 
    group_map( function(.x, .y, select_vect) { 
      df_ind_clean <- .x %>% select(all_of(select_vect)) 
      gt <- gt(df_ind_clean) %>% 
        tab_header(title = paste(title_text, .y)) 
      return(gt) 
    }, 
    select_vect = select_vect)
} 
gt_list <- create_gts_and_map(df = ex_data, group_var = group_var, title_text = "State Chart:")

state_list_temp <- ex_data %>% pull(state_id)
state_list <- unique(state_list_temp)
```

This creates a list of gt tables, `gt_list`. The problem is that when I try to call an element of the list `gt_list$` there are no named objects within the list. So I must call using `gt_list[[i]]`.

What I want to do is build a for loop that matches data from a different data frame (`data2`) to the gts created in the above function. The second set of data is longer and has different data, but the same unique identifier for state ids. However, I am struggling to write the for loop because I don't know how to call corresponding
Using the [[i]] notation here proves useless because each object has different lengths, so `for i in state_list` proves useless.

```
for (i in state_list) {
  
  print(data2$Precipitation[i])
  print(gt_list[[i]])
  
}
```

Which returns the error:

```
Error in gt_list[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
```

How can I call each ID in state_list for both the gt_list and the table? In this case the output would be the precipitation for the state followed by that states gt object. Would I maybe have to change something in the original `group_map`?

My full project is much larger impossible to reproduce here, but solving this small question would help tremendously.

Data

```
ex_data <- structure(list(state_id = c(22L, 22L, 22L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 33L, 
33L, 33L), State = c("California", "California", "California", 
"Texas", "Texas", "Texas", "New Mexico", "New Mexico", "New Mexico"
), City = c("Los Angeles", "San Francisco", "Fresno", "Dallas", 
"Austin", "Frisco", "Albuquerque", "Santa Fe", "Taos"), NumObserved = c(1200000L, 
825000L, 113000L, 240000L, 189000L, 38000L, 56000L, 23000L, 6000L
), Elevation = c(28L, 47L, 235L, 312L, 550L, 128L, 4291L, 3533L, 
7823L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))

data2 <- structure(list(state_id = c(22L, 33L, 42L, 32L, 12L, 14L, 23L, 
11L), State = c("California", "New Mexico", "New York", "Minnesota", 
"Georgia", "Florida", "South Carolina", "Texas"), Precipitation = c(32L, 
8L, 49L, 45L, 38L, 61L, 52L, 24L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `seq_along` instead of the values of the 'state_list' as

```
> state_list
[1] 22 11 33
```

Whereas `gt_list` have only 3 elements, thus looping over the sequence will be able to extract the corresponding elements instead of looping over values

```
for (i in seq_along(state_list)) {
  
 print(data2$Precipitation[data2$state_id == state_list[i]])
 print(gt_list[[i]])
  
}
```

Comment: for the sake of example, I changed the data so that data2 takes a different order from ex_data. how could i do it now? if you do seq_along now it will print the wrong precipitation for the third gt

Comment: @887 Let me know if you want to change the data again.  Thanks Sir